# Geo Nodes: Align point instance to normal - tangent

Tags: normals, geometry-nodes, instances, particle-nodes

I am attempting to replicate blenders particle system alignment using geo nodes. the issue I'm having is that I cant get the particles to stay upright, is it possible to align to something like normal - tangent in the particle system?

Many Thanks!

This is the geo nodes version with node tree:
[image: geonodes]
[image]

and this is what I'm trying to achieve:
All the arrows point downwards while still aligned to normal
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use additional Align Rotation to Vector, but at this time select Pivot Axis, in my case is Y:

[image]

Using this setting, Blender rotates points around local axis Y

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!